# changing default loading page in angular app

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

my current app-routing.module.ts is:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthGuard } from './services/auth-guard.service'; 

const routes: Routes = [

{ path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'login', loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginPageModule' },
{ path: 'home', canActivate: [AuthGuard], loadChildren:'./home/home.module#HomePageModule'},
{ path: 'qr-code', loadChildren: './qr-code/qr-code.module#QrCodePageModule' }
];

@NgModule({
imports: [
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
],
exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

if I want to change the default load page from login (which it currently is) to qr-code, how would I do this? I have tried changing the redirectTo to '/qr-code' but it doesn't work.

Any help would be hugely appreciated, many thanks

Comment: I guess the problem is at other parts. Did you find any errors on the console?

Comment: is qr-code a page?

Comment: Yes it’s a page thanks